# Bash 'times' call outputs two lines, but it's not documented or is unclear what each line represents

Tags: bash

Initially I thought the second line represented the times accumulated by all running scripts, but now I'm not so sure, since I have been getting zero counts for scripts that run for 45 seconds or more.  What do the lines represent?  Also, does bash accumulate user/system time spent in non-bash sub processes?  For example, if you have a script that calls a binary program that runs for a long time, versus a script that calls lots of other short running bash scripts.

`$ ( for (( i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ )) ; do sleep 1 ; done ; times )
0m0.003s 0m0.003s
0m0.003s 0m0.008s`

The documentation is really vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ help times
```

> ```
> times: times
>     Display process times.
>
>     Prints the accumulated user and system times for the shell and all of its
>     child processes.
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Always succeeds.
> ```

```
$ times
0m0.378s 0m0.183s  ## This is the shell's
0m2.134s 0m0.342s  ## This is the child processes'.
```

Another test:

```
$ ( time sha1sum /some/files/* &>/dev/null ; times )
real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.003s
0m0.002s 0m0.002s
0m0.044s 0m0.001s  ## Matches largely child process' runtime.
```

And here's from the source code of Bash 4.0 in `builtins/times.def`:

```
  print_timeval (stdout, &self.ru_utime);
  putchar (' ');
  print_timeval (stdout, &self.ru_stime);
  putchar ('\n');
  print_timeval (stdout, &kids.ru_utime);
  putchar (' ');
  print_timeval (stdout, &kids.ru_stime);
  putchar ('\n');
```

It shows that the first column is the user time while the second one is the system. The shell's time table is printed before the child processes'.

Comment: So "Prints the accumulated user and system times for the shell and all of its child processes." to me suggests both are accumulated totals.  But your comment suggests the second line is accumulated totals of just child processes?  I am being pedantic, but like I said, I am not seeing expected behaviour based on the documentation.

Comment: As an example, I generate this message by reading just the last line: `Script 'jenkins_kcml_build.sh' took 7 minutes 2 seconds (User: 0m0.000s, System: 0m0.000s)`.  How is the accumulated time of the script 0?

Comment: @Craig Bash does not really function when its child process is doing most of the work. And you don't include the sleep time when it waits for input. Everything happens pretty fast.

Comment: @Craig Consider taking a look at the source code I forwarded to my answer.

Comment: You've pretty much answered my question.  So a long running script can accumulate zero time if it delegates all of its work to another process.